# Having a problem getting my output to look a certain way

Tags: python

Thanks for viewing my question and thanks in advance for any help you may provide.
I am writing a program that reads lines from a txt file and then prints the output in a certain fashion.  Here they both are

Here is the txt file I am reading from

```
JOE FRITZ           AMERICAN GOVERNMENT           B
JOE FRITZ           CALCULUS I                    A
JOE FRITZ           COMPUTER PROGRAMMING          B
JOE FRITZ           ENGLISH COMPOSITION           A
LANE SMITH          FUND. OF DATA PROCESSING      B
LANE SMITH          INTERMEDIATE SWIMMING         A
LANE SMITH          INTRO. TO BUSINESS            C
JOHN SPITZ          CHOIR                         C
JOHN SPITZ          COLLEGE STATISTICS            B
JOHN SPITZ          ENGLISH LITERATURE            D
JOHN SPITZ          INTRO. TO BUSINESS            B
```

I am trying to get my output to look like this:

```
                       GRADE REPORT

NAME                COURSE                            GRADE
-----------------------------------------------------------
JOE FRITZ           AMERICAN GOVERNMENT                 B
                    CALCULUS I                          A
                    COMPUTER PROGRAMMING                B
                    ENGLISH COMPOSITION                 A
                    Total courses taken = 4

LANE SMITH          FUND. OF DATA PROCESSING            B
                    INTERMEDIATE SWIMMING               A
                    INTRO. TO BUSINESS                  C
                    Total courses taken = 3

JOHN SPITZ          CHOIR                               C
                    COLLEGE STATISTICS                  B
                    ENGLISH LITERATURE                  D
                    INTRO. TO BUSINESS                  B
                    Total courses taken = 4

Total courses taken by all students = 11

Run complete.  Press the Enter key to exit.
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to your help, I finished this program.

I know it may be ugly, but ATM I am just happy to have the output right.

Here is the source that will display the correct output:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# VARIABLE DEFINITIONS

name = ""
previousName = ""
course = ""
grade = ""
grandTotal = 0
courseCount = 0
eof = False

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONSTANT DEFINITIONS

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

def startUp():
    global gradeFile, grandTotal,courseCount, previousName, name
    grandTotal = 0
    courseCount = 0
    gradeFile = open("grades.txt","r")
    print
    print ("grade report\n").center(60).upper()
    print "name".upper(),"course".rjust(21).upper(),"grade".rjust(33).upper()
    print "-" * 60
    readRecord()


def readRecord():
    global name, course, grade, eof, courseCount

    studentRecord = gradeFile.readline()
    if studentRecord == "":
        eof = True
    else:
        name = studentRecord[0:20]
        course = studentRecord[20:50]
        grade = studentRecord[50:51]
        eof = False

def processRecords():
    global courseCount, previousName, name, grandTotal
    while not eof:
        if name != previousName:
            if name == "JOE FRITZ           ":
                courseCount = 0
                print name + course + "       " + grade
                previousName = name
                courseCount += 1
            else:
                print "\t\t    Total courses taken =",courseCount 
                print
                courseCount = 0
                print name + course + "       " + grade
                previousName = name
                courseCount += 1
        else:
            print (" " * 20) + course + "       " + grade
            courseCount += 1
        grandTotal +=1
        readRecord()
    print "\t\t    Total courses taken =",courseCount


def closeUp():
    gradeFile.close()
    print "\nTotal courses taken by all students =",grandTotal

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROGRAM'S MAIN LOGIC

startUp()
processRecords()
closeUp()

raw_input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

Thanks for your help everyone.  I really do appreciate it.  Sorry if I have frustrated anyone during the process.  Have a good one.  Peace

Comment: what is the output you are seeing?

Comment: @elevendub Great! Keep up the learning!

Comment: @movieyoda: Did you actually read his code?

Comment: @John Don't need to. Y'day he has posted this question 2 times. I helped him in the first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009899/stuck-in-a-while-loop-can-you-please-help That "Great" was for finally getting it.

Comment: @elevendub: `if name == "JOE FRITZ           ":`???
Bad luck if the input data changes slightly. Perhaps you might like to try `if previousName == "": # first student in file` instead. BTW, there are gazillion spaces after the FRITZ, but SO shows only one. Read my lips: "Strip. Trailing. Whitespace."

Comment: Thanks John and movieyoda!! @John you are right, I just could not seem to think it through.  Thanks for shedding light on this for me.  Sorry for frustrating you if I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just figure it out one of the bugs in your code in the function readRecord() you are just reading the first line of your file just it ; you should loop over all lines or make readRecord() a generator .

```
  def readRecord():
     global name, course, grade, eof

     studentRecord = gradeFile.readline()  # <----- HERE

     if studentRecord == "":
        eof = True
     else:
        name = studentRecord[0:20]
        course = studentRecord[20:50]
        grade = studentRecord[50:51]
        eof = False
```

but despite this , to be sincere i don't like your code much, here is what i will do if i were you:

1) get data from file by any way (csv, regex ...) ; i think we have already the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009899/stuck-in-a-while-loop-can-you-please-help)

2) put the data in a dictionary or whatever (so you can manipulate them as you wich).

3) use [itertools.groupby()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by student and to calculate the sum of what you want.

4) use string [Template()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Template), because maybe the format will change, and don't hard code the format of your output like you did.

And please test yours function one by one after write in them , because if you don't it will be hard to figure out which part of the code is not working.

**EDIT:**

and i will not ask you why you want to do this, because if you want to put them in a file again you will have the same problem as before if you want to retrieve them again, and if you objective is just to make a beautiful output i will ask you is it worth it ?

One last advise use a well know format like csv, xml ...

And Good luck :)

Comment: thanks. The thing is that my instructor wants me to use this structure with the multiple functions.  Sorry that my code sucks, but I am trying.  Thanks for the response

Comment: @elevendub : always this teachers with there stupid exercises , but what the hell , you could change the function readRecord() like i told you , if you don't figure this out , please let us know :)

Comment: @elevendub: no the readline() is working fine here, just get the data first from the file and put it in a dictionary then do what ever you want with it;

Comment: @singularity: -1 (1) "get data from file by any way (csv, regex ...)" -- totally irrelevant to reading a fixed-field-width record format (2) "you are just reading the first line of your file just it " -- so how come other records from the file show up in the output? +1 (3) itertools.groupby (4) string.Template

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the 1960s COBOLlocks way that your benighted instructor wants you to do it, but the general ideas are:

(1) [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can save you all that previous/current detecting-name-changed malarky

(2) you should extract your data records into a sensible format up front -- stripping trailing whitespace (always a good idea) gets rid of stray newlines that are not part of the data

(3) global variables used like you are doing are the utter pox (in ANY language).

```
import itertools

guff = """\
JOE FRITZ           AMERICAN GOVERNMENT           B
JOE FRITZ           CALCULUS I                    A
JOE FRITZ           COMPUTER PROGRAMMING          B
JOE FRITZ           ENGLISH COMPOSITION           A
LANE SMITH          FUND. OF DATA PROCESSING      B
LANE SMITH          INTERMEDIATE SWIMMING         A
LANE SMITH          INTRO. TO BUSINESS            C
JOHN SPITZ          CHOIR                         C
JOHN SPITZ          COLLEGE STATISTICS            B
JOHN SPITZ          ENGLISH LITERATURE            D
JOHN SPITZ          INTRO. TO BUSINESS            B
"""

data_source = guff.splitlines(True) # simulate file

columns = (slice(0, 20), slice(20, 50), slice(50, 51))

def data_reader(raw_record_iterator):
    for line in raw_record_iterator:
        yield [line[sl].rstrip() for sl in columns]

def process_file():

    # f = open('my_file.text', 'r')
    # or use a 'with' statement
    # data_source = f

    for key, grouper in itertools.groupby(
            data_reader(data_source), lambda element: element[0]):
        print "=== start student %s ===" % key
        for cooked_record in grouper:
            print cooked_record
        print "=== end student %s ===" % key
    print "=== Grand totals here ==="
    # f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_file()
```

actual output:

```
=== start student JOE FRITZ ===
['JOE FRITZ', 'AMERICAN GOVERNMENT', 'B']
['JOE FRITZ', 'CALCULUS I', 'A']
['JOE FRITZ', 'COMPUTER PROGRAMMING', 'B']
['JOE FRITZ', 'ENGLISH COMPOSITION', 'A']
=== end student JOE FRITZ ===
=== start student LANE SMITH ===
['LANE SMITH', 'FUND. OF DATA PROCESSING', 'B']
['LANE SMITH', 'INTERMEDIATE SWIMMING', 'A']
['LANE SMITH', 'INTRO. TO BUSINESS', 'C']
=== end student LANE SMITH ===
=== start student JOHN SPITZ ===
['JOHN SPITZ', 'CHOIR', 'C']
['JOHN SPITZ', 'COLLEGE STATISTICS', 'B']
['JOHN SPITZ', 'ENGLISH LITERATURE', 'D']
['JOHN SPITZ', 'INTRO. TO BUSINESS', 'B']
=== end student JOHN SPITZ ===
=== Grand totals here ===
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry for the frustration.